# Function Matlab para aproximação de ln(1-x)

Tags: matlab

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom dia pessoal, preciso fazer um Function conforme a imagem, porém não tenho muito conhecimento com o `matlab`, alguém poderia me ajudar ? obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Eu não ia responder, entendo que as pessoas precisam de ajuda, irei fazer minha parte, a fórmula da questão parece muito com a [Série de Taylor](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Taylor) para encontrar [logaritmo natural](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logaritmo_natural)(até onde eu me lembro da universidade lol).

Para escrever uma função utilizando a equação do enunciado é muito simples, o sigma(**Σ**) da fórmula nos diz que você deverá fazer a somatória da equação `(-(x^n)/n)`, a iteração vai de `1` até o `infinito`, não quer dizer que vamos ficar calculando isso até o infinito, na verdade a iteração acabará quando o valor de `n` chegar no limite definido pelo usuário, no enunciado ele deixa explícito algumas coisas, usar o `x` entre `-1 e 1`, ele também diz que `ln(1-x)` é igual a `Σ(-(x^n)/n)`, não vou fazer tudo por você, essa é a função que faz exatamente o cálculo da fórmula `Σ(-(x^n)/n)`:

```
function F = equacao(x,n)
F=0
for n=1:n
     F=F+(-(x^n)/n);
end
end
```

Sim... isso é o que pede a letra `a` da questão, talvez você tenha que criar dentro desta função um `if` que garanta que o seu `x` esteja dentro do intervalo que o exercício pede...

Mas vamos ver se a série de Taylor está correta ? o retorno dessa função é o mesmo que `ln(1-x)`? será que tem alguma função pronta do matlab que calcula isso ? que tal :

```
help log
```

> Compute the natural logarithm, 'ln (X)', for each element of X.

Ao digitar `help log` apareceu esse help sobre a função log,  isso é exatamente o que precisamos né? vamos comparar usando um `x` que esteja dentro do intervalo que o exercício pede, por exemplo `x=0.3`

```
log(1-0.3)

-0.35667
```

Agora vamos tentar usando a função que criei, soma com progressão de `20` (`n=20`), não importa, o exercício da letra `a` foi legal e me deixa usar qualquer valor de `n` e qualquer valor de `x` entre `1 e -1` :

```
equacao(0.3,20)

-0.35667
```

Bingoooo `ln(1-x) é igual a Σ(-(x^n)/n)` huahuahua  SÓ QUE NÃOOOOO... até onde eu me lembre essa série tem uma péssima precisão para calcular o Logaritmo Natural, será que foi por isso que o exercício da letra `c` pediu o erro relativo ? lol...

Já fiz muito, o resto é com você :-)